# Difference between: input-group-prepend & append? (BS4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Could anyone explain the differences between: **input-group-prepend** & **input-group-append**? , i dont find any explanation in the docs.

Comment: Have you checked the CSS? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_input-group.scss

Comment: Pre-pend is before the input, append is after the input. It's basic english

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) it says it's used to place one add-on or button on either side of an input, while prepend its before the input, and append after.

So, `input-group-prepend` should look like:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">preprend</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

And for `input-group-append` :

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">append</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you check the css rules in [_input-group.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_input-group.scss) from Bootstrap 4, you can see they share most of the rules, the important part is to put the div before the input or after.

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxEJaK) using Bootstrap 4 examples.

```css
.show-grid>[class^=col-] {
 padding-top: .75rem;
 padding-bottom: .75rem;
 background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
 border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}

button {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">preprend</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
  
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">append</span>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
```